# Rule based coloured background for labeling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, color, color-ramp, rule-based

I am a newbie working on QGIS 3.6 / Windows 10. I need to label a polygon layer which is categorised by colour.
(pls refer to attached pic as a graphical reference)

[image]

The labels need to have a background which is also categorised by colour (red, orange, yellow and white) according to values in the attribute table of the shapefile.

My understanding is that the map as pictured has been created with an older version of ArcView...

Is it even possible to achieve something similar in QGIS?

Comment: The ability to use the 'single label' method seems to not be available for users with QGIS v3.22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the attribute table of your polygon, you will have a field which dictates the polygon colour, another which dictates the label colour, and another which dictates the label text. I've made a quick example below.

[image]

You can set the layer symbology to 'Categorized' based on your polygon colour field.

[image]

And set you labels to 'Rule-based labelling'. You'll need to set rules as required for your dataset, my example rules follow the format `"Label colour" = 'yellow'` etc. 
[image]
Example output below.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to simply use the @symbol_color variable in the label background expression.

This ensures whatever color your symbols are, your labels are automatically updated, without having to set a seperate CASE statement for the labels:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. In the Layer Properties you can set you labels. 
You can either set rule based labeling with a filter expression for all your categories with a defined background.
Or you can add single labels and add a expression similar to this for the background color:

```
CASE 
  WHEN   "objectid" = 1 THEN color_rgb( 0,0,0) 
  WHEN   "objectid" = 2 THEN color_rgb( 10,0,0)
 END
```

You can find more on labeling in qgis here:
https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. In the labeling tool, enable Background

[image]

and in the Data defined override write the following

```
Case
When "id" in (1,5,9,15) then 'yellow'
When "id" in (2,7,10,13) then 'blue'
When "id" in (4,11,14,119) then 'orange'
else 'white'
end
```

Change the "id" to the field name that contains the numbers for your case, and the change numbers in the brackets to the numbers that you want to highlight.

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're able to make your label's background "data-defined" :

In your layer's properties go to **label/background/stroke color** click on the drop-down menu and make the colour data-defined using the expression builder.
You able to reference any of **your table's attribute** and make it conditionnal (if needed) using **if or case** statements.

Comment: stroke or fill color ... to be more precise ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Here's an example where the background color of the label (the name of the flower) depends on the specie (field "art").

[image]

Go to the layer's styling, choose which field to label (here "art") and background. (Alt. choose Layer Properties - Labels - Background)

[image]

Set rules for the **fill** color: click on the button to the right [image] and choose Edit. (After a rule is set, this button turns yellow.)
Use conditionals `case when "art"= ...` (the field "art" is set to be the label) and `color_rgb` to set the color (or color_cmyk a.o.). Use color_rgba or color_cmyka if you want to add alpha (transparency) component.

[image]

Looking for colors: http://colorbrewer2.org - gives you rgb and cmyk values.