# Building a rectangle around a font marker using the geometry generator

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry-generator

In able to show labels in a legend 
(see my other question regarding the legend here: [QGIS styling a legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332734/qgis-styling-a-legend/332812#332812))
I need to show points as rectangles with the same height but a length based on the length of text in a font marker.

This is a screen view of the points with the font markers with text of differing length.
[image]

I tried the buffer function but have so far only busted my brain because I could not work out how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Do you simply want to label the points and shall the labels have a background? Then have a look at the option `background` (Hintergrund) in the labeling tab of the layerproperties. If not, please explain more detailled, what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I cannot show labels in a legend as I was taught in my other query here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332734/qgis-styling-a-legend?noredirect=1#comment543032_332734
So I need to create a points layer style similar to what the labels look like-

Comment: Ah, German bureaucratic maps. Those are bad cartographic practice, but I know, "we always did it this way"... bla. Two things: 1. Having many labels on a small scale map will render it next to useless when it comes to easily and efficiently transport your information. 2. In my opinion it would be easier to use coloured labels and add the symbols of the labels to the legend manually.

Comment: @Erik, you speak my mind re. German buerocracy :D
But who am I to argue with my boss as the mere QGIS monkey that I am... ;)

Comment: Would creating the symbols for the legend manually be an issue? Either workloadwise, or are you creating an online-map rather than PDF/paper?

Comment: no, its not an issue but these codes / the legend might be amended in the futureand I wanted to find the cleverest way to do it.
The other idea I had was to style excel tables accordingly and import them as csv files into the legend.

Comment: Afaik .csv don't save styling, so importing a .csv would be of any help - but I might be wrong. Side-note: With you being the "GIS-monkey", this should give you sufficient cartographic knowledge to advise your boss on matters of best practice.

Comment: @Antje I answered your original post with a way to put text on the legend icons, using a 'dummy' layer for legend purposes. That leaves you still able to use labels for your original polygons without needing to show that in the legend. Have a look and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Good news, bad news.

This code creates a polygon based on your point geometry, currently 40 m wide and 20 m high (if using a m-based CRS)

```
make_polygon( make_line( make_point($x-20,$y-10), make_point($x+20,$y-10), make_point($x+20,$y+10), make_point($x-20,$y+10), make_point($x-20,$y-10)))
```

But since it is based on the CRS of the layer, it is slightly rotated.

Also, the rectangle is not filled. So I think you'd be better of with the "manual legend" approach.

Comment: If you put this in the geometry generator you should be able to choose any polygon fill style you want.

Comment: I filled it blue (tripple checked) but didn't get a fill (QGIS 3.4.9).

Comment: Thank you :) -The code works just fine generating a rectangle. I do have the same problem as @Erik tho. Even tho I chose a coulour to fill the rectangle it does not show in the map. (It is however changed in the Layer properties / styling window)
-Do you think that is a bug? (I work with QGIS 3.6.3)

Comment: The rectangle is not rotated (probably because I'm working with a rather obscure CRS: EPSG:3068 - DHDN / Soldner Berlin) It only applies for Berlin so no distortion due to earth curvature ;)

Comment: I have the same result, a polygon with no fill. I used the `geometry by expression` tool to generate a new layer with that expression, and it's still a polygon with no fill. Using the `geom_to_wkt` function reveals that it's actually four separate invalid geometries, which means there's something wrong with the way it's constructed. I suspect the points are joined in the wrong order.

Comment: Try drawing the rectangle out on a piece of paper, with each corner labeled with its coordinates. Draw arrows from the starting corner around the outside of the rectangle and back to the same corner. Use that diagram as a guide to help you write the corner coordinates in the correct order.

Comment: *make_polygon* needs a LineString for each ring. *make_line* creates a linestring with _n_ vertices, so you can create just a closed linestring with 4 vertices (+ 1 to close it), with: `make_polygon( make_line( make_point($x-20,$y-10), make_point($x+20,$y-10), make_point($x+20,$y+10), make_point($x-20,$y+10), make_point($x-20,$y-10)))`. The output is valid polygon with just one ring and can be filled.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielDeLuca. I never used the feature before.