# Add 'Abc' to styles in legend

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, legend

Is there a way to add a 'dummy' label to symbols in the legend such as this? [image: Symbol with 'dummy' label inside]

The layer it self has a brown/red outline, as shown in the image, and labels are turned on. Since there are a ton of different numbers and letters for each shape in the layer, I want to show a simple outline with a 'dummy' label.

I've tried the method suggested by [csk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332734/qgis-styling-a-legend), but I'm aiming at getting only one symbol - not one for the symbol and one for the label.