# Rule-based labeling with optional second field

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, expression, rule-based

I need to label some polygons with 2 fields using only one label:

The first being a field in the attribute table named `"Bio-Code"` the second one being optional if a cell in the field `"BBT-Code"` is filled with numbers.

The first field and second field should be separated by a slash `"/"` (not the slash used as operator)

[image: example]

I have yet not been successful at creating an appropriate expression.
Could you point out where I have made mistakes?

```sql
Bio_Code
/
CASE
WHEN "BBT_CODE" IS '12500' THEN '12500'
WHEN "BBT_CODE" IS '12714' THEN '12714'
WHEN "BBT_CODE" IS '715212' THEN '715212'
WHEN "BBT_CODE" IS '715222' THEN '715222'
WHEN "BBT_CODE" IS NULL THEN 'None'
END
```

Comment: If you use `Single labels` instead of rule-based, you could try the following expression: `if("BBT_CODE" is not NULL, "Bio_Code" || ' / ' || "BBT_CODE", "Bio_Code")`

Comment: @Joseph has it correct, this is way easier.

Comment: hmmm, thanks :) This leads to another question which I am struggling with: How do I make these 2 labels placed next to each other? The "offset" function seems to be working with the background only... Also QGIS shows only 1 label even if I use the "placement" function and chosing "around centroid" for one label and "offset from centroid" for the other...

Comment: @AntjeHolderbach Joseph's solution does create a single label, not two, therefore I don't understand your question. If it is important, maybe ask a separate, new question?

Comment: I misunderstood @Joseph and after some more thinking the penny finally dropped and I tried what he was suggesting and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 7):

If you use **Single labels** instead of *rule-based*, you could concatenate more than one field using `||`. Couple this with an `if` statement, you could try the following expression:

```
if("BBT_CODE" is not NULL, "Bio_Code" || ' / ' || "BBT_CODE", "Bio_Code")
```

Comment: I need to use rule based labeling because I need to have a different couloured background according to a value. See my other question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332720/rule-based-coloured-background-for-labeling-in-qgis/332788#332788

Comment: @AntjeHolderbach as the second answer to your linked question states, you may base your label background on values of the attribute table.

Comment: this method will work with rule-based labeling just as well as it does with single labels.